# Batch add string before filename

Tags: string, batch-rename

I'm working on a Windows batch file and I need to change name of files in current direcotry.

I have these files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

and I need to add string "REG~" before each filename like this

```
REG~file1.txt
REG~file2.txt
REG~file3.txt
```

Thank you.

Comment: are you using any programming language? what did you try?

Comment: I tried to do this manually renaming each files. But i have almost 1000 of such files and may be more. So I am seeking help if it is possible to do by running a BATCH file.

Comment: Take a look: http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off    
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION    
SET old=file  
SET new=REG~file   
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.txt') do (    
    SET newname=%%f    
    SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!    
move "%%f" "!newname!"    
)
```

What this does is it loops over all .txt files in the folder where the batch file is located and replaces the file with December inside the filenames.

Comment: Thanks. But what it did is, it replaced the old file name to "REG~.txt"!

Comment: It works fine in my pc. Copy,paste code in your batch file and run without any change.

Comment: I am sorry, I was running the BATCH incorrectly. It finally worked. Thanks so much for the help. It saved almost half a day's effort.

Comment: Good thing you came here Saheli ; anytime you repeat the exact same task more than 2 times, it means it can be automated, and it should !

Comment: I'm honestly surprised this was the selected answer. It's not compact at all, and it's kind of difficult to understand what at all it's doing. The answer by @foxidrive is very simple.

Answer (score 6):

Run this in a folder with .txt files in it.  Use test files first.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do ren "%%a" "REG~%%a.tmp"
ren *.tmp *.
```

Comment: How did you use it?  It works fine here.  Put it in a folder with some .txt files a launch the batch file.

Comment: for the first iteration it append correctly, but for second iteration will append again REG~REG~

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles on to this, just one tweak to this code - add "txt" (or the appropriate file extension) to the very end:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do ren "%%a" "REG~%%a.tmp"
ren *.tmp *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using windows, this work for me.

If you want to add any prefix to file names, it can be done as in the below example. Here we try to add ‘photo’ to every txt file in the current folder and subfolders.

forfiles /S /M *.txt /C "cmd /c rename @file photo@file"

Source: https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-file-extensions-bulk/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Powershell, the following in a `.bat` would do too (and more powerful.):

`powershell.exe -command "get-childitem *.txt | rename-item -newname  { 'REG~' + $_.Name }"`

Answer (score 0):

use this in command prompt

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren "%a" "REG~%a"
```

or for batch file/scheduler change the `%a` to `%%a`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren "%%a" "REG~%%a"
```

it use for loop and wildcard file with txt extension `*.txt`